# Is my query correct? Can I optimize it? Positive sum and negative sum of integers

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two solutions for finding the sum of positive integers and negative integers. Please,tell which one is more correct and more optimized?
Or  Is there any other more optimized and correct query ?
Q:

Consider Table A with col1 and below values.

```
col1

20
-20
40
-40
-30
30
```

I need below output

```
POSITIVE_SUM    NEGATIVE_SUM

90               -90
```

I have two solutions.

/*q1*/

```
  select POSITIVE_SUM,NEGATIVE_SUM from
     (select distinct sum(a2.col1) AS "POSITIVE_SUM" from A a1 join A a2 on a2.col1>0 
     group by a1.col1)
     t1

 ,
 (select distinct sum(a2.col1) AS "NEGATIVE_SUM"from A a1 join A a2 on a2.col1<0 
 group by a1.col1) t2;
```

/*q2*/

```
select sum (case when a1.col1 >= 0 then a1.col1 else 0 end) as positive_sum,
       sum (case when a1.col1 < 0 then  a1.col1 else 0 end) as negative_sum
from A a1;
```

```
    POSITIVE_SUM    NEGATIVE_SUM

    90                  -90
```

Comment: The second one is much better. You can always check execution plan and see it yourself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second query is not only better performing, but it returns the correct values.  If you run the first query, you'll see that it returns multiple rows.

I think for the first query, you are looking for something like:

```
select p.positive_sum, n.negative_sum
from (select sum(col1) as positive_sum from a1 where col1 > 0) p cross join
     (select sum(col1) as negative_sum from a1 where col1 < 0) n
```

And that you are asking wither the `case` expression is faster than the `where`.

What you are missing is that this version needs to scan the table *twice*.  Reading data is generally more expensive than any functions on data elements.

Sometimes the second query might have very similar performance.  I can think of three cases.  First is when there is a clustered index on `col1`.  Second is when `col1` is used as a partitioning key.  And third is on very small amounts of data (say data that fits on a single data page).

Answer (score 3):

I wonder how you even came up with your 1st solution:
- self-join (twice) the table, 
- producing `6` (identical) rows each and finally with `distinct` get 1 row, 
- then cross join the 2 results. 
I prepared a [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=9bc71501279f8446ac13759d7b2efaaa) so you can see the steps that lead to the result of your 1st solution.
I don't know if this can be in any way optimized, 
but is there case that it can beat a single scan of the table with conditional aggregation like your 2nd solution?
I don't think so.

Comment: Yes - query 1 is total logical nonsense.